# Octave's 'clc' does not clean the Command Window right after the call

Tags: terminal, octave

This command line

```
octave:78> for n = 1:3; clc; printf ("----\n"); end
```

will result in

```
----
----
----
octave:79> _
```

why is it that the screen is not cleaned after each line is printed?

The result that I would expect is:

```
----
octave:79> _
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"clc" and "home" calls readlines rl_clear_screen (Have a look at oct-rl-edit.c:octave_rl_clear_screen). As you can read from the comment above, some systems doesn't export "_rl_clear_screen" so as a temporarly fix redisplay was redefined to do nothing.

See here: http://hg.octave.org/octave/file/281a36ad4907/liboctave/util/oct-rl-edit.c#l77

What problem triggers this in your application? You can manually fflush (stdout) if you want this.

Comment: That's was actually the problem, the screen did not update in subsequent calls. `for n = 1:3; clc; printf ("----\n"); fflush (stdout); end` works perfectly.